# SQL Searching a String for Numbers between different criteria

Tags: sql, string, excel, vba

I have been attempting this issue for a while and have yet to find a solution.

I am looking for a method using SQL commands to Search a String for an alphanumeric number between 2 points.

For example of Dataset in table Showing:

***---Added---***
The Numbering sequence I am searching goes as follows

```
A=[a-z,A-Z]
#=[0-9]
X=[a-z,A-Z,0-9] or can be missing

AA###XX-XX-A##-####-###-X
```

***------***

**[MyList]** Column Example
***Updated Example***

```
AA123A-ZT-A01-2222
AB2121A-JR-A02-22222
AA2138A-AD-A03-222
....
AA3174A-KV-C01-22222
AA762A-AS-C02-2222
AA317AA-WG-C03-22222
AA576A-BB-C04-2222
AA345A-SG-C05-22222
AA862A-ER-C06-2222
AA9871A-HD-A07-22222
....
```

What I need help with is to do this:

`SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE MyList BETWEEN '-C02' AND '-C05'`

My initial Attempts where a combination of LIKE and BETWEEN. I have tried a few different methods and still no luck.

The SQL I am using is the Microsoft JET OLEDB 4.0. Ultimately this is going to be used within excel 2007 (but needs to be backward compatible with 2003) with to search a huge (In terms of Excel) data table for specific data.

Any help or Direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the two end points always fixed?  Are you always comparing to the third element in the string?  Does this component always follow the pattern of alpha + number?

Comment: The end points are not always fixed within the string. It will always be the 3rd grouping I am comparing between the '-'. Unfortunately the pattern is almost similar to above, The A Grouping however can consist of any Letter or Number [a-z,A-Z,0-9].

Comment: Your Example doesn't represent all forms of your Number Sequence. Looking at your Number Sequence is looks like your second grouping is optional and that somethings the 3rd grouping could be the 2nd grouping. If the second grouping is missing do the dashes remain? Also, Are you trying to query another excel file from an Excel file? I don't understand why you are using SQL. Are you trying to get data from an Excel file into an application you are building? Or are you trying to get the Data to Excel from another source? What source if so? Text file, Access DB, SQL Server, CSV?

Comment: I see the sequence does not match. I originally removed the last bit since I didn't think it was relevant and I can modify any solution to the format. What I missed was the explanation that the initial A's and B's in my example could be both letters and numbers.

Comment: Yes, I am querying another excel file that is being generated by another program. I am using SQL because I have some understanding on how to write scripts to get the data, and it is the easiest method I have come up with. Ideally I would like to have data in an DB of some sort but that is an extra step or have no access. This Macro needs to be usable by average user. Essentially I am getting a summary/count of data based on Criteria in an large external excel file that was generate. The original source is more than likely an oracle db that I have no access to other then the report generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that commented and user1845791 I was able to find the solution to my original question.

So using Excel with JET 4.0 to search for a range within a Column Data set based on criteria.

**SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE Document MyList LIKE '%-C0[2-5]%'
```

Helpful Resorce at [Microsoft Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208897%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE MyList LIKE '%-C%'
      AND LEFT(SUBSTRING(MyList, PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%', MyList), 50), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', SUBSTRING(MyList, PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%', MyList), 50) + 'X')-1) BETWEEN '01' AND '05'
```

The second condition on the where clause returns the first number from the string.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server

Comment: The PATINDEX SQL command apparently isn't available within the Microsoft Jet Engine.